# Rank in Tableau with Continuous date trend

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get Top 10 products and their sales trend by order date (with exact date format). Also these Top 10 products should change w.r.t value selected as per customer segment filter.

As we need to apply ranking after filter selection so used index calculation and Top N parameter to restrict the data for Top products. I have uploaded the workbook at following URL

https://public.tableau.com/profile/nileshpatil#!/vizhome/Top10Rank/Top10Products?publish=yes

First tab shows working of Top 10 products and in the second tab added order date (continuous format) to show sales trend by the order date but Index function not working correctly. Its giving incorrect ranking and  also same product got multiple index values. what I am looking for sales trend for the Top 10 products as per filter selection.  When converted this date to discrete then (refer third tab ) then Top 10 product details are correct but its not showing trend considering its discrete date.

Please note I cant use Context filters instead of index table calculation for TOP filtration considering my actual dashboard has got filters from secondary data source and I think you can't include dimensions filters from secondary data source into context.

Can someone please provide suggestions on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit hard to answer these type of questions without understanding the raw data format or knowing what fields are currently being used within the worksheet.  In the future, it would be helpful to provide more detail, raw data, or make the workbook downloadable!

Most likely the proper index values can be obtained by configuring your table calculation compute method properly, or by using a Level of Detail ([LOD](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html)) calculations.

You should be able to create a calculated field that aggregates all sales for a product excluding the date (or other) dimensions.  You can then use this field to filter the top 10 products properly.  Add in a table calculation as you were doing before to sort if desired.

Let me know if you need more clarification.